# Steps on how to make a website? I learned HTML and CSS, what now?

Tags: web-development, website-design

So I just finished learning HTML, HTML5 and CSS... (From books I got online, online tutorials and online courses) I want to have test project on how to actually get my website up and running online. What's my next step?

What programming language should I go for next to enhance my web development and app creation? Do I go for PHP? C++? Java/jQuery? etc?

And can anybody cite or give a link to a or their web design process? 
How do I begin the workflow?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: If you want to create a static website, go for JavaScript/jQuery. If you want to create a dynamic website, go for PHP (server language). If you want to create a web application, go for Java (server language).

Comment: "**finished** learning"?!

Comment: This question is not a good fit for this site.   For one it covers a lot of ground and is "too broad".    It is also asking for recommendations.  Such questions don't work well here because the attract spam and opinions as answers.

Comment: It also appears that the original poster may have tried to edit the question through a second account.   Major edits to a question should be done with the same account that posted it.

Comment: There is no animosity meant by the quizzing of your "finished learning" statement ... but you must realise that it doesn't make a whole lot of sense when used in this context, unless you have literally "given up" - and I'm sure you haven't. Best of luck with the studies. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have not finished learning. After ten years I still learn on a daily basis (which I love!). But, there's a point which could be considered "enough knowledge to proceed", I assume you mean that.

Then another correction, you wrote 'Java/jQuery'. I assume you ment Java*script*. Java and Javascript are two different things and can't be used for the both thing.

---

*And now for an actual answer:*
**Come up with a small project and build it**. The only way you can truely learn the skills needed is by doing them, applying them. Book knowledge is a nice start, but not it's not real-world-knowledge.

I've learned the most by making my own sites, I wanted things to be done properly, not "meh, this'll work too". Just start on a project. It might fail as a website, but it's a learning project, thát's the goal. Push your limits, try new techniques.

This takes time.

I suggest you try to improve your html and css skills first, you will run into the limitations of html very quick. A simple page system will be next. From there on, research what you need. Real tutorials for scripts you need so you understand what they do rather than just copying them and leave it.